# Methods to install custom style properties in GTK+-widgets

Tags: css, c, gtk, gnome, gdk

I'm writing custom *GtkWidgets* for a small library and therefore need custom style properties. I usually use the [gtk_widget_class_install_style_property](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-class-install-style-property)-function during the class-initialisation to do that. However I could not find a way to install a color-property, such as a *GdkRGBA* or a *GdkColor* for a widget. How could I do that?

Most of the available functions for installing or registering style-properties are deprecated since the move to the *CssProvider* for style-handling and it is sometimes hard to get the best way of handling with style-properties in gtk from the reference manuals.

Is there a different way to install such properties? Furthermore is there a documentation how the *CssStyleProvider* works internally and how properties are parsed from a css-file to the actual widget or *GtkStyleContext*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so with

```
gtk_widget_class_install_style_property (widget_class,
    g_param_spec_boxed ("color-property", "Short name of property",
         "Long description of the color property",
         GDK_TYPE_COLOR,
         G_PARAM_READWRITE));
```

However, I don't think there's anything you can do with a color-typed style property that you can't do better with just plain CSS.

Comment: Yes thanks for the answer. I think I simply misunderstood the boxed-type parameters of GLib. And I was just confused about the correct use of Gtk-Widget-Style-Properties, but now it seems they also will be deprecated in the near future according to the [GTK+ Roadmap](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/Roadmap).

Comment: Deprecated, but only removed in GTK 4.0. Presumably there will be something else equivalent by that time, like the ability to install custom CSS properties.